How To Unquote Numeric Properties In Vue
When assigning attributes to components in the template section of Vue, values of numeric props are placed inside quotes which tend to generate a lot of warning in the console. Even after removing them manually they always return after formatting the document. I've read the prettier documentation and this was on their page, "Prettier doesn’t unquote numeric properties for Vue" I want to know if there's a way to work around it and remove the quotes on numeric properties.
After formatting the document everything appears like this
        <star-rating
          class="star"
          :show-rating="false"
          star-size="15"
          active-color="#f54748"
          :increment="1"
          glow="2"
          :active-on-click="true"
          v-model:rating="averageRatings[product.id]"
          :read-only="true">
        </star-rating>

instead of
        <star-rating
          class="star"
          :show-rating="false"
          star-size=15
          active-color="#f54748"
          :increment="1
          glow=2
          :active-on-click="true"
          v-model:rating="averageRatings[product.id]"
          :read-only="true"
        ></star-rating>


This is likely XY problem. What are you trying to do? Provide a value for numeric prop? It should be :glow="2" and not glow="2", the quotes are irrelevant

@EstusFlask Thanks....the reason why I wanted to see if there's a work around was the heap load of warnings that were appearing in the console but since it's irrelevant, I  guess I'll leave it like that....Thanks again
